# Where can I find a list of approximate excitation energies?

Tags: energy, nuclear-physics, atomic-excitation

I would like to know the excitation energies for the known states of various nuclides. Is there a list somewhere that has this documented? I can't seem to find them easily for many nuclides. Maybe I have something mixed up in my head.

Also, is there an approximate way to calculate them, at least for nuclides with low nucleon count?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Is this what you are after: "[NIST Atomic Spectra Database](http://www.nist.gov/pml/data/asd.cfm)".
- Are  you referring to the "[Rydberg formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rydberg_formula)" for "describing the wavelengths of spectral lines of many chemical elements"?